# mySQL "UPDATE table SET..." not updating column

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I got multiple queries in my node.js app, that updates columns in tables, but one specific column that's being updated just doesn't update by some queries and stays the same.

This doesn't happen randomly its still the same queries and other queries update it just fine. I checked code but there's no problem and it doesn't matter how many columns I try to update that one just in some queries doesn't update and I **there's no error**, so there's no problem with the syntax I guess

code: `` con.query(`UPDATE table SET column1= column1+${variable1}, column2 = column2+${variable2} WHERE id = ${message.author.id}`); ``

Comment: Hi! I would recommend to you to debug what's the result of `column1+${variable1}` ... the plus (+) operator in JS sometimes do weird things. BUT, if Mysql is not throwing an exception, then the generated column name could be OK, then, I would go to inspect what is the output of `${message.author.id}` .... in simplier words: debug output of variables. What do you think of? When this kind of things happens, I usually take the generated SQL, and run it directly in MySQL, just to be sure it is an error scoped to application.

Comment: @paulmartimx I tried to debug the variables, but they show the values they should, so I have no idea what could make this happen and I have in code basically identical queries to this query that works fine. And I tried to run it directly in MySQL and it worked.

Comment: And it happens every time in the same queries and other queries works fine every time

Comment: OK! So, some times happens to my development enviroment, that Mysql simply ignores some queries for no reason. The only workaroung has been to restart both: dev server and Mysql. Could you try only for being sure?

Comment: I can't restart the entire server, because its hosted on virtual machine and I only have access to my db, not the entire server.

Comment: Well, then it seems that kind of errors that are difficult to track down. But, if there is a pattern as you said "This doesn't happen randomly its still the same queries..." there must be something in the code, then.

Comment: Maybe you could try to echo the actual SQL statement this generates? That's likely to point you in a direction as to what is happening where.

Comment: Just in case, are you sure your query is run ? First idea would be your con hangs (and you have multiple ones which could explain why other query succeed), but more probably depending on your driver, you miss a "con(...).exec()". Seems pretty naive, but it happens...

Comment: Yes the query actually runs(checked it by adding another column to query that updates fine, but the first column still doesn't updates)

Comment: Unless you can provide us with a reperformable example, it is unlikely that we can help.